# Database changes is not reflected to joomla website

Tags: php, caching, joomla, webserver

I am making changes on a website database I am developing using joomla 2.5 , but these changes are not reflected on the website.
I dumped the database and run it on the same version of the website locally and it is working very fine with the changes , I have only one database on the webserver so no doubt that I am changing on other database , when I changes the database password the website went down
I am installing my joomla web application on a godaddy webserver and I also cleared the cache to make sure that it is not the problem.
the changes are on a modules and also on the articles

Comment: @Anne I just cleared cache and edited the configuration.php and set cache time to 0 but I got no changes reflected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, are you are you are editing the correct database? I only say this as I have a similar problem where I was registering test accounts on my site and couldn't see the rows being added to the database cause I was looking at the Wamp Server one, not the online one.

If noting what so ever is happening like you said, try changing the database table prefixes but do not update the `config.php` and see if this throws an error when you try and preview the site.

Comment: I changed the suffix and it throws this error 
"Table 'ecojoomlaintelio.wcu93s_session' doesn't exist SQL=INSERT INTO `wcu93s_session` (`session_id`, `client_id`, `time`) VALUES ('b9rdpt5pem3d4fvlb7ji8kgpm7', 0, '1341401758')"
ecojoomlaintelio is the name of my database
when I change the name of my database in joomla the website still working very fine also it still work when I changed the database password
My whole website is online nothing is running locally

Comment: it's impossible for the joomla site to carry on working if you change the database name, username or password. It will immediately throw errors at you until the configuration.php is also updated. Im not sure what else is going on cause I don't have access to your site

Comment: :S I figured out that I am installed Joomla on a previously installed joomla database , so I have tables for both Installations in the same database with different prefixes
thank you very much changing the database table prefixes made me figure out that issue

Answer (score 0):

I think Database changes which you are making are module specific and they arte getting  which you are **re-initialized** while accessing module through init function of module.   You can change values over there also

Comment: what do you mean by re-initialized??
Actually can you make your answer more clear please?